# electric truck motor mass

Tags: power, motor

I'm thinking about an electric truck of 20tons total mass, accelerating to 100kph in 20s. Top speed 160kph. What electric motors would be needed for this? How much would they weigh?

*I calculated on some site (http://www.robotshop.com/blog/en/drive-motor-sizing-tool-9698) that this would need a total of 2000kW and 17000Nm. Feel free to dispute this claim. Battery shall not be part of this equation. 
Could this motor(s) that I need for this be lighter than 2 tons? 
I only found 500kW motors of 1ton, I refuse to believe that for my numbers I need 4tons of electric motors...*

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Show your calculations. Show your "some site" link. "*I refuse to believe ...*" Explain why using numbers. What has top speed got to do with it? This is an engineering site so I'm afraid you have to show some design calculations.

Comment: You cannot ignore air resistance at higher speeds. Also, you should consider the grade. What is the maximum grade you need to ascend? Also, would you allow a multi-speed transmission?

Comment: Which country? As in the UK the construction and Use regulations specify the minimum power to weight ratio ...

Comment: I used this calculator: http://www.robotshop.com/blog/en/drive-motor-sizing-tool-9698

Comment: I used an incline of 0%, I thought it would be fine with more torque than a Diesel motor. Transmission would be needed I guess, unless it's possible to have enough torque at low speed and still be able to reach 160kph all without a transmission

Comment: What values did you put into the calculator?

Comment: 20000 kg - 1 motor - radius 0.4m - velocity 45m/s - 0deg incline - acceleration 1.4 m/s² -

Comment: tinypic link doesn't work.

Comment: I saw, I wrote the numbers in th comment above

Comment: You specified acceleration time to 100kph, but not from there to 160kph. Do you want constant acceleration all the way to top speed? (this will need a lot more power). Also a motor that size should be able to achieve at least 80% efficiency.

Comment: If you really want the motor light, try relaxing your operating time requirement. E.g. if you just run for 20 seconds you can just over drive a smaller motor and cutoff before it over heats. Similarly use a water cooled motor and cool it with ice water.

Comment: But E=m*v^2/2, you are looking at 7.7MJ of energy at 20s, which is at least 385KW. Battery is indeed part of the equation here, because if you want the lightest motor, you want to drive it in a constant-torque fashion, e.g. you use the maximum torque through the acceleration process. But practically that's not possible because it will be too much power at high speed and would over load the electrical system and battery. In reality you possible would use a hybrid: at low speed drive the motor to max torque, then drive it at battery's maximum power.

Comment: Air resistance is a major factor in power requirement above say 10 kph. Any calculator that does not factor this in has no hope of giving a good answer. Power = 0.5 x Cd x Df x A x V^3. | Cd = drag coefficienct - start with 1 = flat plate drag. For Si units A in square meters , Df = fluid density = 1.2 kg/m^3 for air at SL. V in m/s .Power in Watts. So eg a 4 m^2 frontal area truck at 100 kph  = 27.8 = say 30 m/s requires 0.5 x 1.2x 1 x 4 x 30^3 =  65 kW to combat air resistance alone. Improve Cd. Reduce area. ...

Comment: battery is not a problem because I want to power the truck externally, like a tram. But ofc there will still need to be a backup / buffer battery for a range of 25km maybe. For in cities it must be able to ride on its own. But there you wouldn't accelerate like a madman, so some 750kg battery should be enough...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with electrical design

Answer (score 2):

Let's work out thrust first, then consider torque. Thrust is forward force. We will start by ignoring wind resistance just to make the calculations easier.

100 kph = 27.8 m/s.

27.8 m/s / 20 s = 1.4 m/s/s

So you need to accelerate at 1.4 meters / second /second. Thrust force can be found using F = M * A. You gave the mass as 20 tons, which is 20,000 kg.

F = 20,000 kg * 1.4 m/s/s = 28,000 Newtons.

So that is the forward force or thrust needed. The wheel torque is just thrust multiplied by wheel radius. Let's say the wheel radius is 0.5m.

28,000 Newtons * 0.5m = 14,000 Nm of torque at the drive wheel. If there is a reduction gear, then the motor torque could be smaller. Let's say it is a 10:1 total reduction. Then the motor torque could be 1,400 Newton meters.

160 km/hr = 44 m/s.
circumference of 0.5m radius tire is 3.14m.
44 m/s / 3.14m = 14 Hz. So the 10:1 reduction gives a maximum motor speed of  14 * 10 = 140 Hz, which is 8400 RPM.

So, you would be looking for a motor which can produce more than 1400 Newton meters of torque at moderate speeds, and has a maximum speed of 8400 RPM or more. The motor may not need to produce full torque at 8400 RPM.

My main takeaway from this is that you definitely want to use a multi-speed transmission. Because the motor specification doesn't sound very reasonable. But hopefully you can do some of your own calculations now.

There is one more thing to calculate. Motor power is motor speed * motor torque, except that speed has to be measured in radians per second. The power of a motor will usually be specified at its "rated speed."

Let's say our motor rated speed is 1800 RPM (a ballpark figure) and torque is 1400 Nm.

1800 RPM = 30 Hz.

30 * 2 * pi = 188.5 rad/sec.

So motor power is 188.5 rad/sec * 1400 Nm = 264 kW.
264 kW is around 350 HP.

Note that a typical industrial motor will produce constant torque from very low speed all the way up to rated speed. It can also produce more torque for short periods, but may overheat if it produces extra torque for an extended period.

Hope that helps. It is hard to find all this information in one place.

Comment: The point of this post is to show how the calculations work. Hopefully the OP can now run some calculations with multi-speed transmissions and get an idea of how much motor is really needed. I imagine it will be roughly 2/3 to 3/4 the power output of the internal combustion motor.

Comment: Hm, thx, at least I understand now what is going on. All in one place. Only thing left is to tweak the numbers and find the fitting motor (which will not be easy) and see how little it can weigh. - Anyone know a good place to pick an electric motor?

Comment: Well, industry motors weigh a lot, easily 2 tons for a 375kW electric motor... but Tesla uses very high revving (10krpm) AC induction motors: https://chargedevs.com/newswire/elon-musk-cooling-not-power-to-weight-ratio-is-the-challenge-with-ac-induction-motors/ and get 362hp out of 32kg (70 pounds). That would theoretically mean roughly 45kg per 375kW motor, of which I would put 4 in there. 180kg. . . So because it's a truck, it must endure a much harder life, and last for 1Mio km. I'd say 500kg, all ultra durable, should be fine. . ?

Comment: I believe the tesla motor was developed specially for the car. I assume the development process was expensive. I am not sure you want to use it as your basis for power to weight. Also, if you have a multi-speed transmission, there isn't much benefit to a high-speed motor. You will just need to use a larger reduction gear ratio, since the fastest your wheels will ever spin is 700 or 800 rpm.

Comment: http://www.evwest.com/catalog/index.php?cPath=8